Android Studio latest version gradle update problem
After updating Android Studio to the latest Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 and Gradle plugin to 8.6.0, I am getting these compile-time errors and am unable to create a build.

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'AndApp'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with name 'lintDebug' not found in project ':app'.

build.gradle code here
android {
    compileSdk 35
    buildToolsVersion = '35.0.0'
    ndkVersion "26.2.11394342"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain {
            languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of("17"))
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 35
    }

    applicationVariants.configureEach {
        def variantName = name.capitalize()
        def lintTask = tasks.named("lint${variantName}")
        assembleProvider.get().dependsOn.add(lintTask)
    }    
}

ExternalApiUsageException error in the latest gradle update (8.6.0).
Task with name 'lintDebug' not found in the project ':app'.
Exception is:

org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating
root project 'AndApp'."
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.ExternalApiUsageException:
org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with name 'lintDebug' not
found in project ':app'.  at
com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:71)
at
com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:54)`

Can someone please help me resolve these issues ?
Code where it's got an error
applicationVariants.configureEach {
     def variantName = name.capitalize()
     def lintTask = tasks.named("lint${variantName}")  // error line
     assembleProvider.get().dependsOn.add(lintTask)
}


If you run ./gradlew tasks --all, does lintDebug appear in the output for your desired module?

@CommonsWare Yes.

Instead of directly referencing the lint tasks by their name, you can retrieve all lint tasks dynamically with tasks.withType and then configure dependencies.
Try updating your applicationVariants.configureEach block as below:
applicationVariants.configureEach { variant ->
    def lintTaskName = "lint${variant.name.capitalize()}"
    tasks.matching { it.name == lintTaskName }.configureEach { lintTask ->
        assembleProvider.get().dependsOn(lintTask)
    }
}

If the above solution doesn't work then try this.
applicationVariants.configureEach { variant ->
    def lintTask = tasks.findByName("lint${variant.name.capitalize()}")
    if (lintTask != null) {
        assembleProvider.get().dependsOn(lintTask)
    }
}

